# How to decide when the car is parked in ios?

Tags: ios, core-motion

I am developing an app where the requirement is when the app is running it should detect when the user parked there car.

One [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35790497/ios-cmmotionactivity-manager-how-to-detect-stop-signs-when-the-car-is-stop) I found is check the status of coremotion and when the car is moving it will detect status as "automotive" and when parked(user will start walking from the car) the status will be "walking". Thats how you will know the car is parked.

But coremotion is not that responsive in detecting walking. And it sometimes gives false positive. Are there other ways we can find out whether car is parked/completely stopped?

Comment: There is now 100% way to do this, What if your use is on a bus, plane, train, etc...
You could also use the GPS to detect the user speed of movement, but again this could yield in a large amount of false positives.

Comment: @rckoenes Thanks for your response. My assumption is that the app will be used only while in car. I thought of using GPS but sometimes when you are in car in congested traffic your speed will be really slow which will give false posative.

Comment: Even using the core motion will not help you here. There is just now why to detect that the user is in the car or not. Let alone if he/she parked the car,

Comment: There probably is nothing you can do for that. The entire parking interaction or even trying to slowly find a parking spot can be considered walking. You probably have to some logic on your own detecting actual parking movements. And even then you almost certainly will not be sure as to when the car is actually parked and the user starts walking instead of simply backing up one last time in the parking spot.

Comment: What about location manager?

Comment: This is definitely a non-trivial problem, as you can have both false positives and false negatives. Based solely on sensors within the device, it's really a lot of guesswork (based on detecting "steps" for instance) that will be more or less effective. Another option could be to try to detect a BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy aka Smart Bluetooth) device stored in the car, or possibly part of the car equipment itself.

Comment: Are you sure that core-motion will help you?

Comment: We actually tried an implementation of beacons, and iOS was the laughably disappointing on iPhone 5s and iPhone 5Ss - it just doesn't work the way they say, and you can't just exclude those devices when you release an app. Android is simply much better at BLE (unless it's a Nexus 4). You can't even change the scan interval on iOS

Comment: Did you reach some useful solution at the end?